# Laravel Allow Only registered users to read a html generated magazine (pdf) from FlippingBook

Tags: html, laravel, generated-code

In Laravel I want to let only registered user to access and read a html generated magazine in Flipping book (It generates a html/flash magazine with ui), it generates index.html . This would be done by a route filter if it where a view. But since i have generated code is there a way to do this without rewriting the code that flipping book generated (maybe with .htaccess) to let only registered users read the magazines? and redirect not logged in to main page?

[Flipping book example magazine](https://flippingbook.com/online-digital-magazine) (also flipping book generates for whole page not as modal)

Any hint or help would be appriciated thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the route, add the middleware option for auth.  This will redirect people when someone tries to access the route that hasn't logged in.

```
Route::get('magazine', ['uses' => 'SomeController@someMethod', 'middleware' => 'auth']);
```

Comment: Thank you for the help, Will try something like this out, but wouldnt unregistered user still get to it from public folder? (i think this generated code should be there but could be wrong)

Comment: Yeah they might be able to, I did not realize the file was going to be publicly accessible so my method won't work.  I think an easy way to do this would be to move the file into a different directory which is not publicly accessible and use Laravel to get and display the contents of that file.

Comment: `public function loadMagazine($number)
    {
        
          return File::get(base_path() . '\magazines\number'.$number.'\index.html');

    }` so i am trying like this but this only loads html not the generated css and javascript (i know im using something wrong but dont know what)

Comment: I have done it by putting it into the public folder but still used middleware so im gonna Mark your answer for solved. Thank you